# Angular Property does not exist on type error

Tags: html, angular, http, webapi

in my service I have:

```
getCart(): Observable<Cart[]> {

    return this.http.get<Cart[]>(`${this.myApiUrl}/data/`); 
 }
```

in my component I have:

```
my_data: Cart[]=[]

public loadCart() {

 this.cart_Service.getCart().subscribe((data: Cart[]) => this.my_data = data);

}
```

in HTML file I have:

```
<div *ngIf=" my_data">
    <p>  Grand Total : {{ my_data.grandTotal }} </p>
</div>
```

I get the error saying that:"Property 'grandTotal' does not exist on type 'Cart[]'" can anyone help me to fix this error? I tried many online solutions but it did not work.

Comment: It looks like `my_data` is an array so it won't have the `grandTotal` property. You either have used the wrong type (`Cart[]`) or you need to iterate through the array. If you can give us some sample data returned from the API, we could help further.

Comment: thanks for the answer. in my models I have export class Cart {
    
    id :number;

    cartItems :(CartItem)[];

    grandTotal: number;

}

Comment: I think you just need to change the type from `Cart[]` to `Cart`.

Comment: Actually I tried it before but it did not work

Comment: can you try in your HTML to put  my_data[0].grandTotal instead of  my_data.grandTotal? just for troubleshooting

Comment: thanks for the answer. It says : "my_data[0] is undefined"

Comment: thanks for trying, can you please edit your question and include the response your are getting from the request(refer to the network tab of your the developer console of the browser)?

Comment: I get this error in my browser: GEThttp://localhost:4200/api/Cart//data/ not found and I get this error in terminal of vs code :error TS2339: Property 'grandTotal' does not exist on type 'Cart[]'.

Comment: can you please try to call the endpoint using postman or another software to make sure the endpoint is working? and please make sure you don't put 2 slashes in the url like the one you commented

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224910/discussion-between-vfx-and-mzg). recommended by Stackoverflow

Comment: yes I tested my end points with postman and they worked fine. Also I checked the slashes. but It did not work.

Comment: I believe your angular application is running on port 4200 not your api server, so I think you need to change the port number in this url http://localhost:4200/api/Cart//data/ ---- and use the correct port number of your api local server

Comment: It gives the same error.

Comment: that is weird, can you please move to the chat to solve the problem faster?

Comment: I did a small example that does what you need and I tested it, you just need to replace the port in the api url to match the one of your local server and please notice that you need to include http NOT https in the api url
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-empty-project-vw3wzg?file=app/app.component.html

Comment: thank you for the answer I tried it but it did not work.

Comment: I believe now you will be able to upload a picture of the error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally fixed this. In my component I changed the type of my_data to any;

```
my_data: any;
```

I also changed the getCart() function like this:

```
getCart(): Observable<Cart[]> {

    return this.http.get<Cart[]>(this.myAppUrl + this.myApiUrl);
}
```

Comment: congrats for solving the problem, I would like to bring to your attention that 1) as a best practice using stricter types is better than using more general types, so it is not recommended to use type "any" when you are sure the type will be Cart[], and in case the type Cart[] is causing you a problem it is better to ask about the problem to fix it and make it work the proper way.
2) One more thing is that defining the "myAppUrl" variable inside each service is not a good practice and you should consider defining it inside angular environment variables files
https://angular.io/guide/build